# Why are my tomato seedlings dying after applying ammonium sulfate?

Tags: tomatoes, seedlings

Why are my tomato seedlings dying? They just germinated then after a week some are dying? I added compost and a little bit of ammonium sulphate in each plastic bags. They are not yet transplanted. I want to know why because I do not see any pest.

Comment: What was the reason for applying ammonium sulphate?

Comment: How much did you add?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by 'plastic bags', does that mean that's how you've germinated your seeds? Otherwise, a photo would be helpful, but adding ammonium sulphate to seedlings is not a good idea - the nitrogen will be too high for them at this stage (assuming they've just germinated or only have 2 pairs of leaves), plus it contains even more sulfur than it does nitrogen, and sulfur is usually applied to alkaline soils. Whilst tomatoes prefer a neutral to slightly acid soil ph,  the sulfur wouldn't be helpful, especially at the seedling stage. Equally the 'compost' you mention - not sure what that means, garden compost you've made yourself perhaps? If you do mean that, it was too soon to add it; it should only be added once the seedlings become plants in pots of their own, and only then if it was produced using a hot aerobic composting system.